# Exporting a code-created Steema chart with custom image

Tags: c#, teechart

### Is there some way to export a Steema Chart with custom drawings without passing a "screen draw"?

I'm trying to export a Steema `TChart` that hasn't been drawn on screen with some custom drawings on it. I found the `Graphics3D` object, but when I try to use it it throws a `NullReferenceException` :

> at Steema.TeeChart.WPF.Drawing.Graphics3DWPF.Draw(Rect destRect, Rect srcRect, BitmapSource image, Boolean transparent)
>     at Steema.TeeChart.WPF.Drawing.Graphics3D.Draw(Rect r, BitmapSource image, Boolean transparent)
>     at WpfSteemaApplication.MainWindowViewModel.SaveImage() ...

The only other information regarding custom drawing I have found is in the events `BeginDraw` and `AfterDraw`, which doesn't seem to be called before I export my image.
However, everything else seems to render just fine, it's just my custom image that I need as well.

```
private void SaveImage()
{
    BitmapSource bitmap = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/button.png"));
    TChart chart = new TChart();
    JPEGFormat jpegFormat = chart.Export.Image.JPEG;

    // This throws an exception when uncommented.
    //chart.Graphics3D.Draw(new Rect(0, 0, 100, 100), bitmap, true);
    Line line = new Line();
    line.FillSampleValues();
    chart.Series.Add(line);
    jpegFormat.Width = 1024;
    jpegFormat.Height = 340;
    jpegFormat.Quality = 100;
    jpegFormat.Save("C:\\Temp\\steemachart.jpg");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the `DoInvalidate()` method on the chart which in turn calls `AfterDraw`. When exporting the image after that both the image and the chart is rendered in the image

```
private void SaveImage()
{
    TChart chart = new TChart();
    JPEGFormat jpegFormat = chart.Export.Image.JPEG;
    Line line = new Line();
    line.FillSampleValues();
    chart.Series.Add(line);
    jpegFormat.Width = 1024;
    jpegFormat.Height = 340;
    jpegFormat.Quality = 100;
    chart.AfterDraw += OnAfterDraw;
    chart.DoInvalidate();
    jpegFormat.Save("C:\\Temp\\steemachart.jpg");
}

private void OnAfterDraw(object sender, Graphics3D g)
{
    BitmapSource bitmap = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/button.png"));
    g.Draw(new Rect(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height), bitmap, true);
}
```